# iPhone Copy/Paste

Tags: iphone

I want two buttons in the app in a certain view, Copy and Paste.  This view also has a textview. If someone presses the copy button, I want all of the text in that textview to be copied. If someone presses the past button, I want to append the text in the textview with that which is in the clipboard? How do I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)copy {
    pasteboard = [textField text];
}

-(IBAction)paste {
    [textField setText:[[textField text] stringByAppendingString:pasteboard] ];
}
```

where `pasteboard` is a `NSString`

Answer (score 1):

Use [UIPasteBoard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)